# Previous button click starts at parent instead of cycling through children in menu

Tags: jquery, menu

```
$('.navigation a.prev').on('click', function(){
    if(!$("#menu ul li.active").length){
        return false;
    }

    if($("#menu ul li.active").prev().length){
        if($("#menu>ul>li.active").find('li').last().length && !$("#menu>ul>li.active").find('li.active').length){
            $("#menu ul li.active").find('li').last().children('a').click();
        } else {
            $("#menu ul li.active").prev().children('a').click();
        }
    } else {
        if($("#menu ul li.active").closest('li').prev().length){
            $("#menu ul li.active").closest('li').prev().children('a').click();
        }
    }

    return false;
});


<div class="menu" id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="ajax/2.html" rel="ajax-content">About</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/4.html" rel="ajax-content">Objectives</a></li>
<li class="sub-menu"><a href="ajax/5.html" rel="ajax-content">**Importance**</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="ajax/9.html" rel="ajax-content">Need</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/13.html" rel="ajax-content">**Benefits**</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="sub-menu">
<a href="ajax/14.html" rel="ajax-content">District</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="ajax/15.html" rel="ajax-content">Perspective</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/17.html" rel="ajax-content">Example</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/19.html" rel="ajax-content">Leadership</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/20.html" rel="ajax-content">**Engaging**</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

I need to be able to click the prev button through every menu item.

If current menu is on **"Engaging"** sub menu, I click previous when it gets to Perspective and I click previous it jumps **"Importance"** click previous again it goes to **"Benefits"**

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well? Maybe even produce a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't match your question and the JavaScript that you include. (For example there's no element in your HTML that would be selected by `$('.navigation a.prev')`).

Comment: The example in your fiddle cycles through all the items in the menu, just as you describe. I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: Its not quite there.  It cycles through but it always loads the parent then cycles through the children, its skipping all children first and selecting the parent.  I want to cycle through the children then the parent

Comment: It looks like the parent item is being skipped.  It cycles through the sub menu but never loads the parent item. do you see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you actually have *two* `li` elements that have the `active` class assigned to them: the parent menu item, and the sub-menu item.

This code should take that into account:

```
$('.navigation a.prev').on('click', function () {
    var $activeItems = $("#menu ul li.active");
    if (!$activeItems.length) {
        return false;
    }

    var $parentItem = $activeItems.eq(0);
    var $subItem = $activeItems.eq(1);

    var $prevSubItem = $subItem.prev();
    if ($prevSubItem.length) {
        $prevSubItem.children('a').click();
    } 
    else {
        // If there is a sub-item currently selected
        if($subItem.length) {
            $parentItem.children('a').click();
        }
        else {
            var $prevParentItem = $parentItem.prev();
            if($prevParentItem.length) {
                $prevParentItem.find('a').last().click();
            }                
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rSV45/8/

In the example, only the backwards navigation works correctly, but you can use a similar approach to handle the forward navigation.

Comment: @user2761496 - I've updated my post in response to your comment. (BTW, if you're commenting on an answer it's usually good practice to add the comment to the answer itself, rather than the original question.)

Comment: Sorry about that.  Thanks for the help.  Send me your email.  I owe you a gift card.